# How can I query pairwise event attendance in MS Access given its subquery restrictions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My colleague and I have been wracking our heads on this for days and have come to the conclusion that we just don't know SQL well enough to solve this problem.  Please help us!

We have a table in MS Access called EventAttendance with 2 fields: MemberID (the person who attended the event) and EventID (the event they attended).  Unique Member and Event IDs are stored in their own tables (Member and Event, respectively.)  EventAttendance contains entries for hundreds of members and events, but a simple collection of records for 3 events might look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      MemberID       |     EventID      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

In this example, Member 1 attended Events 1, 2, & 3; Member 2 attended Events 1 & 2; Member 3 attended Events 2 & 3; and Member 4 attended Events 1 & 3.

We are now trying to create a table that documents how often each pair of members attended an event together.  Ideally, we would want the table to look like the one below (for the example records above), where CoAttendance is the number of events each pair attended together:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Member1        |     Member2      |   CoAttendance   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         3        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         4        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         3        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         4        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         4        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

This has proven a lot more challenging than we assumed.  First, we haven't been able to figure out to get pairs in such a way that combinations don't repeat, but we have been able to list all permutations by querying a perfect copy of the Member Table (MemberClone) and using the following query:

```
SELECT Member.MemberID AS Member1, MemberClone.MemberID AS Member2
FROM Member, MemberClone;
```

This query resulted in a table like so:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Member1        |      Member2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Not perfect, but good enough (this is a problem we'd like solved eventually, but not the main one.)

The bigger problem is getting the third column (CoAttendance) to work.  The closest we've gotten to a solution is through the use of subqueries:

```
SELECT Member.MemberID AS Member1, MemberClone.MemberID AS Member2,
(SELECT Count(*)
  FROM (SELECT EventID FROM EventAttendance WHERE EventAttendance.MemberID = Member1) AS Member1Attendance
  INNER JOIN (SELECT EventID FROM EventAttendance WHERE EventAttendance.MemberID = Member2) AS Member2Attendance
  ON Member1Attendance.EventID = Member2Attendance.EventID) AS CoAttendance
FROM MemberClone, Member;
```

This should theoretically generate a list of only events that Member1 and Member2 attended together for each pair, and the count(*) operation would count those events.

The problem is that Access subqueries can only see one level above themselves, so Member1 and Member2 are undefined in the nested subqueries (they are defined 2 levels above.)  I've tried finding solutions, but find that I just don't understand SQL enough to process similar solutions posted elsewhere (e.g., [Nested subquery in Access alias causing "enter parameter value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121634/nested-subquery-in-access-alias-causing-enter-parameter-value)) while also making the inner join work.

Any help you can offer would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a self-join with aggregation:

```
select ea1.memberid, ea2.memberid, count(*) as num_events
from EventAttendance as ea1 inner join
     EventAttendance as ea2
     on ea1.eventid = ea2.eventid and ea1.memberid < ea2.memberid
group by ea1.memberid, ea2.memberid;
```

MS Access might be finicky about the `<` in the `on` clause.  This is an `inner join`, so you can do:

```
select ea1.memberid, ea2.memberid, count(*) as num_events
from EventAttendance as ea1 inner join
     EventAttendance as ea2
     on ea1.eventid = ea2.eventid 
where ea1.memberid < ea2.memberid
group by ea1.memberid, ea2.memberid;
```

Comment: It works!  I haven't quite wrapped my head around it, but it works!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This requires doing a match finding all people from events (so a self-join on EventAttendance)

SQL for this is below

```
SELECT Member.ID AS Member1, Member_1.ID AS Member2, Count(EventAttendance_1.Event_ID) AS CountOfEvent_ID
FROM (Member INNER JOIN (EventAttendance INNER JOIN EventAttendance AS EventAttendance_1 ON EventAttendance.Event_ID = EventAttendance_1.Event_ID) ON Member.ID = EventAttendance.Member_ID) INNER JOIN Member AS Member_1 ON EventAttendance_1.Member_ID = Member_1.ID
GROUP BY Member.ID, Member_1.ID
HAVING (((Member_1.ID)>[Member].[ID]));
```

That is the SQL provided by Access for the following setup:
[image: Access query design]

Note that you do not necessarily need links to Member or Member_1 - just that you may want to get info about them other than their ID.

---- Update

Gah this is basically the same answer as @Gordon's above (so I've upvoted his). I've not deleted this one in case you find the picture useful (when using Access, I much prefer the GUI query designer).

Comment: Thanks!  I went with @Gordon's answer because it was more compact, but yours helps me understand what was going on a bit better.